# How to print lld in Lua 5.3

Tags: lua, string.format, lua-5.3

```
string.format (formatstring, ···)
```

Returns a formatted version of its variable number of arguments following the description given in its first argument (which must be a string). The format string follows the same rules as the ISO C function sprintf. The only differences are that the options/modifiers `*, h, L, l, n, and p` are not supported and that there is an extra option, `q`.

Lua 5.3 doesn't support `lld`, how can I print `lld` in Lua 5.3?

Comment: The question was modified to a different one by you. In C, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, and `uint64` are three different types, it's not clear what you are asking. I have rolled it back. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use `%d`.

---

In C `sprintf`, `%lld` is used to format a `long long` type, which is an integer type at least 64 bit.

In Lua 5.3, the type `number` has two internal representations, integer and float. Integer representation is 64-bit in standard Lua. You can use `%d` to print it no matter its internal representation:

```
print(string.format("%d", 2^62))
```

Output: `4611686018427387904`

---

In Lua source file `luaconf.h`, you can see that Lua converts `%d` to the approapriate format:

```
#define LUA_INTEGER_FMT     "%" LUA_INTEGER_FRMLEN "d"
```

and `LUA_INTEGER_FRMLEN` is defined as `""`, `"l"` or `"ll"` if different internal representation for integer is used:

```
#if defined(LLONG_MAX)      /* { */
/* use ISO C99 stuff */
#define LUA_INTEGER     long long
#define LUA_INTEGER_FRMLEN  "ll"
//...
```

Comment: bad argument #2 to 'format' (number has no integer representation)

Comment: print(string.format("%d", 9223372036854775807))
assert( 2^63 == 9223372036854775807 )
print(string.format("%d", 2^63))   -- bad argument #2 to 'format' (number has no integer representation)
why?

Comment: @Sleepwom The biggest number that can be represented in a signed 64-bit is `2^63 - 1`, read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: how to print unsigned 64-bit?

Comment: Use `string.format( "%u", 1 << 63 )`. Don't use the `^` operator to create large integers (because it doesn't create integers but floats).